# TypeScript type guard issue

Tags: typescript, typeguards

Consider following code:

```
interface XBase {
    a: string;
}
interface X1 extends XBase {
    v1: string;
}
interface X2 extends XBase {
    v2: string; // A
}
function isX1(arg: X1 | X2): arg is X1 {
    return (arg as Partial<X1>).v1 !== undefined;
}
function isX2(arg: X1 | X2): arg is X2 {
    return (arg as Partial<X1>).v1 === undefined;
}
function f(x: X1 | X2) {
    const x1a = isX1(x) ? x : undefined;
    const x1b = isX2(x) ? undefined : x;
    if (x1a) { console.log(x1a.v1); }
    if (x1b) { console.log(x1b.v1); }
}
```

This works as expected.

When the line marked `A` is removed, the type of `x1b` changes to `undefined`.

Why?

Using tsc version 4.9.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the line marked A is removed, the type of x1b changes to undefined.
>
> Why?

When you remove that line, everything that is an `X1` is also an `X2`. Remember that an object is allowed to have excess properties, so something that's an `X2` must have `a: string`, but it could also have arbitrary other properties, including a `v1` which is a string. Thus, `{ a: 'foo', v1: 'bar' }` is an `X2` as well as an `X1` (as well as an `XBase`)

Because of this, typescript deduces that it's impossible for `isX2` to return false. If you pass in an `X2`, then obviously your function will return that it's an `X2`. But if you pass in an `X1` then as far as the types are concerned, it must be an `X2`, and so typescript expects your function will return true as well. Since it always returns true, `x1b` must always be undefined.

Now your actual implementation of `isX2` wouldn't let a `V1` slip through, but the types say it would. It's a bit ugly but you could change your return type on `isX2` to specify that not only is the value an `X2`, but it doesn't have a `v1` property.

```
function isX2(arg: X1 | X2): arg is X2 & { v1: undefined } {
    return (arg as Partial<X1>).v1 === undefined;
}
```

With that modification, it's no longer guaranteed that an `X1` would return true.

In practice this type of situation doesn't come up much. Most of the time, if you're writing an X2 type it's because you want to add some distinguishing features to it, like you had before commenting out line `A`. And this will only come up when you don't have those distinguishing features.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBoCE4GcUG8BQyRycAXMlmFKAOYDc%20AvvqJLIiqgIzIQAekEABMsaTDmQFiyAG5dylaiHpMW4aPCRoATLwERhojNjyFiAenOztCqrTrJLyAIKqYAVxAIwwAPYhkYCxuAAo4KBpybmQAHx0ASnJwmkCjHiliKAgwdygAsIiSUQAFcJ84ABsAHm4APniAOjlkAEIAXjbkTyEIGFAIIQZmDy8ff1TUbQLItB44ycSSQqCdZAAySVl5LuFe-qFkRkkzIiycvORpouRSqHLqusbmjs7uvZABofwR7z8AmBCfCicwSx2kCH8lGQfC4cGQnSCoT48WQAH5ochyG8%20h9BidkBCQFCYQAjeETKbItE7Ho4gaY6EMaTAGCXGFwFG4AmQ3wVCANCq%20GiA2FNLjxBzMZmskUkzncom8-mC4WksUSw5MIA)

Comment: Good answer. One note - `isX1()` and `isX2()` return a boolean. If one fixes that, it also produces the type errors you'd expect. One thing that confused me looking into this... as-is when passing in an X2 the 'type' of x  inside `f()` is never. Why is that?

Comment: If i understand your question, you're saying you start with the code in the question, then comment out line a, then hover over the `x` on line 18 and see `never` and are wondering why? That would be because typescript deduces that the second part of the ternary expression on line 18 can't execute, so it narrows the type to `never`. If i misunderstood the setup for the question, please let me know.

Comment: you understood. Thanks. My comment above is incorrect. I just read about typescript 'predicates' (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates). Ugh that's confusing though, looks like it's returning a boolean.

Comment: They should be using `in` anyways to check if a property exists in the value, not if it's undefined or not.

Comment: @NicholasTower I thought about it a bit and I think I get it, thanks!

Comment: @vera. Using `in` breaks when refactoring.